# Scala: How to use negation in filter or use to check condition which is not present in column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

suppose the column is in this way

OPEN
acb
abc
bcv
abc

i want to filter out in another dataframe which are not **abc** in OPEN in scala.
where OPEN is column and is present in a dataframe and want to check condition using the column and dataframe.
I tried

```
val k = DF.filter("OPEN" != \"abc\"")
```

But still its not filtering out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with Spark SQL:

```
case class Data(open: String)
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(Data("acb"), Data("abc"), Data("bcv"), Data("abc")))
df.where($"open" !== "abc").show()
+----+
|open|
+----+
| acb|
| bcv|
+----+
```